# How to decompose a 5-cycles into a permutationproduct of two 3-cycles?

Tags: permutation, group-theory

We know that every 3-cycles can be expressed as the product of two commutations.

```
Cycles[{{1, 2, 3}}] == 
 PermutationProduct[Cycles[{{1, 3}}], Cycles[{{3, 2}}]]
```

In the same way, we can see that each 5-cycles can be expressed by the product of two 3-cycles:

```
Cycles[{{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}}] == 
 PermutationProduct[Cycles[{{1, 2, 3}}], Cycles[{{1, 4, 5}}]]
```

And, we can also see that each 3-cycles can be expressed by the product of two 5-cycles.

```
Cycles[{{1, 2, 3}}] == PermutationProduct[Cycles[{{5, 4, 2, 1, 3}}], 
 Cycles[{{1, 3, 2, 4, 5}}]]
```

How can I customize a function `generator[lis_List] := Module[{}, ...]` to find all the possible products of two 3-cycles of a 5-cycles?

For example, enter `generator[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}]` to get:

```
{{{1, 2, 3}, {1, 4, 5}},
 {{3, 4, 5}, {3, 1, 2}},
 {{2, 3, 4}, {2, 5, 1}},...}
```

A general idea is as follows, but it is too complicated. I hope there is a more ingenious method:

```
Threecircleslist = 
  Flatten[Permutations /@ Subsets[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {3}], 1] // 
   DeleteDuplicates;
data = Flatten[
    Table[{Cycles[{i}], Cycles[{j}]}, {i, Threecircleslist}, {j, 
      Threecircleslist}], 1] // DeleteDuplicates;
Select[data, 
 PermutationProduct[#[[1]], #[[2]]] == Cycles[{{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}}] &]
```

```
{  {Cycles[{{1, 2, 3}}], Cycles[{{1, 4, 5}}]}, 
   {Cycles[{{1, 2, 5}}], Cycles[{{3, 4, 5}}]}, 
   {Cycles[{{1, 4, 5}}], Cycles[{{2, 3, 4}}]}, 
   {Cycles[{{2, 3, 4}}], Cycles[{{1, 2, 5}}]}, 
   {Cycles[{{3, 4, 5}}], Cycles[{{1, 2, 3}}]}}
```

Comment: @kglr I've corrected that mistake, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe something like

```
ClearAll[threeCycles, toThreeCycles]
threeCycles[{a_, b___}] := Flatten[{a, #}] & /@ Partition[{b}, 2]

toThreeCycles[pc_Cycles] := Module[{perms = 
    Permute[pc[[1,1]], CyclicGroup[Length @ pc[[1,1]]]]}, 
  Map[Map[Cycles @* List] @* threeCycles] @ perms]
```

***Example:***

```
toThreeCycles[Cycles[{{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}}]] // Column
```

[image]

```
PermutationProduct @ ## == Cycles[{{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}}] & @@@ 
   toThreeCycles[Cycles[{{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}}]]
```

> ```
> {True, True, True, True, True}
> ```

**Note:** `Cycles` are *automatically canonicalized* ([`Cycles >> Details`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Cycles.html)):

[image]

Thus,

```
Equal[Cycles[{{1, 2, 3}}], Cycles[{{2, 3, 1}}], Cycles[{{3, 1, 2}}]]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

So if the desired output is a list of pairs of `Cycles` objects `toThreeCycles` does the job.

If the desired output is a list of pairs of triples, then you can explode the output from `toThreeCycles` by taking, for each pair `{Cycles{{a,b,c}}], Cycles[{{e,f,g}]}`, tuples of cyclic permutations of `{a,b,c}` and `{e,f,g}` as follows:

```
explode = Apply[Join] @* ReplaceAll[{a_Cycles, b_Cycles} :> 
   Tuples[Permute[#[[1, 1]], CyclicGroup[Length @ #[[1, 1]]]] & /@ {a,   b}]];

explode @ toThreeCycles[Cycles[{{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}}]] // 
 Multicolumn[#, 3, Appearance -> "Horizontal"] &
```

[image]

Comment: Your code seems to have some syntax errors, I can't get the desired results.

Comment: @Alittlemouseonthepampas, was missing ` @` after `Length`. Fixed now.